# How append a Content Property value to the Title (for Save As)

Tags: microsoft-word

We are creating a template for Invoices.

In the template (and therefore the document) the **Document Title** is set to "Invoice".
We have also added a **Building Block Content Control Property** called "invoice-number" - which is entered by the User.

How can we append the 'invoice-number' to the Title, so that on Save, it is filed as 'Invoice-nnn'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Building Block Content Control calls up various building blocks. Instead, try repurposing the Title Document Property Content Control under Quick Parts. See my page: https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart. Have you user add the number to the Text "Invoice" already shown in that content control.

Comment: You are conflating Building Blocks, Content Controls and Document Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using SharePoint, there's only really one reasonably simple way to do this in Word that is reasonably straightforward for the end user and does not rely on coding in, say, VBA, and that's to use a legacy Form Field code to enter the invoice number, and a `{ TITLE }` field code to set the `Title` property.

That requires that you also *protect* all or part of the document because that is needed to make that type of form work. Protecting part of a document can create other limitations, e.g. where the user is unable to work with certain types of content.

If you also want to ensure that the Title is part of the document's file name on disk, that requires coding anyway.

If your documents are being served from SharePoint, it may be possible to set the Title using a SharePoint column formula when the document is saved. (As it happens, I don't think you can but I'd have to check).

The only reason that this can work without code is that legacy forms have a "Calculate on exit" option that means that all field results are recalculated when the user tabs out of a field where that option is set. It's unfortunate that there is no equivalent when you are using Content Controls, Content Controls, but that's just the way it is.

At this point, you should probably do a bit of research on making a form using Legacy form fields, but to as an example of how it works, you could do this:

In the Developer Tab, in the Controls group, click the dropdown that leads to the `Legacy Forms` and `ActiveX Controls` icons. Click the `Text Form Field` icon in the `Legacy Forms` section. Don't use the `ActiveX Control`.

This inserts a FORMTEXT field into your document. You can use Alt-F9 (typically) as necessary to display the actual form field.

Select the field and use the `Properties` option to set the Type, maximum length etc. I wouldn't put anything in the `Default Text` box.

Change the `Bookmark` name to, say, `InvoiceNum`.

Ensure the `Fill-in enabled` box is checked. Check the `Calculate on exit` box. Use the `Add Help Text` button to add a tip if you want, then click `OK`.

After that, you need to insert some field codes that will set the document Title to "Invoice-" followed by the number entered in the form field. You surround that by a `{ SET }` field to prevent the resulting TITLE from being displayed. So...

Click after the for field, and use ctrl-F9 (typically) to enter a pair of the special field code braces `{  }`.

Inside that, type `SET X`    so you have

```
{ SET X   }
```

After the "X ", use ctrl-F9 again so you have

```
{ SET X {  } }
```

Inside those inner {  }, type `TITLE "Invoice-"`   so you have

```
{ SET X { TITLE "Invoice-" } }
```

Click immediately after the `-` and use ctrl-F9 to insert another pair of field braces, so you have

```
{ SET X { TITLE "Invoice-{  }" } }
```

Inside those braces, type the "Bookmark" name that you entered in the Form field's properties box, so you have, e.g.

```
{ SET X { TITLE "Invoice-{ InvoiceNum }" } }
```

NB, you can't just type any of these `{  }` using the keyboard. You have to create the field brace pairs using ctrl-F9 or equivalent.

Now before you can use the form, you have to protect it. To do that, in the `Protect` group, click `Restrict Editing`, check `Allow only this type of editing in the document` and select `Filling in forms` in the dropdown.

Then click Yes, Start Enforcing Protection. Word will prompt for a password. For now, I'd ignore it.

You should now be able to type a number into the form field. But you have to click the tab to "Exit the field" so that the Title is updated. You should be able to check that the Title *is* being updating using `File-> Info`. To modify the form etc. you first have to go back to the `Restrict Editing` Task Pane and click `Stop Protection`.

If you actually really needed to use Content Controls in your document, you can mix Content Controls and the older Form Fields, but that can cause another set of problems.

To do this with Content Controls alone, your main options would be...

Just use the Title Content control instead of the FORMFIELD, but prepopulate it with the prefix `Invoice-` Then the user has to know that they aren't supposed to change that text but are just supposed to add the invoice number after that, then "Exit the content control". Or you could add any other mapped Content Control such as the Company Fax Number control, modify its title, then insert a similar set of fields to the above, except they would look like this:

```
{ SET X { TITLE "Invoice-[AnotherCopyOfTheMappedContentControl]" } }
```

(i.e. you literally insert another copy of that control after `Invoice-` )

In that case, the user has to know that they have to exit the content control, then select the document (say, using control-A, and predd F9 to update all the field codes).

I wouldn't personally want to ask my users to remember any of that stuff but I expect it is a workable option in some environments.

Comment: Instead of a Title DocProperty field and legacy formfields, use the Title Document Property Content Control from QuickParts.

Comment: The Title Document Property Content Control both reflects and sets the Title Document Property. It displays the property's content and if changed/edited, it changes that content in the document property. It acts like a DocProperty field that can not only show the property's value, but editi it directly.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer.  It will take me some time to digest :)   fyi I did find and use your .../word/MappedControls page and already included appropriate bits in my Invoice.  Thank you for providing it all to the community.